# phpdoctrine save collection of differents entities

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have interface:

```
interface Product
{
    function getAmount();
}
```

and php doctine entities:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="orders")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Order
{
    private $products = array();

    public function addProduct(Product $product){
        $this->products[] = $product;
    }

    public function getProducts() {
        return $this->products;
    }

    function getAmount() {
        $amount = 0;
        foreach ($this->products as $product) {
            $amount += $product->getAmount();
        }

        return $amount;
    }
}
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="books")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Book implements Product
{
    function getAmount() {
        return 1;
    }
}
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="pens")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Pen implements Product
{
    function getAmount()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Book, Pen - are different entities and table. How to implement relationship Order::products with collection of Books, Pens, etc(for save in database)?

I understand that two solutions to this problem.
The first is when saving(and loading) to the database manually convert this relationship to map(array of entities names and ids).
This decision I do not like.
And the second is to correct architecture. I do not know how. Most likely already have a ready-made solution ... Help please.

Answer (score 0):

i'am not sure you can get it exactly that way.

- whether you define a separate Entity Poduct and add a column **product_type** where you tell whether it book, pen or what ever.

  in entity Product that property should be defined as **enum** and it can be tricky(depends on what do you use besides doctrine)
- or you make it for each product type (what can be pretty fast to a nightmare).   I'd guess you have ManyToMany Relation. most probably it should look smth. like that.

in Order

```
 /**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Book")
 * @JoinTable(name="Order_Book",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="book_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
 protected $book;

 /**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Pen")
 * @JoinTable(name="Order_Pen",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="pen_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
 protected $pen;
```

and in Book:

```
  /*
  * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Order", mappedBy="book")
  */
  protected $order;
```

with Pen and others the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at inheritance mapping: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html